# ¿Por qué pierde calidad este icono? Java Swing Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en el que hago uso de imágenes propias para que se vean en la aplicación. Resulta que al poner la imagen en Netbeans, esta pierde calidad, os pongo una comparación:

[image: Imagen en Netbeans]

Y lo que debería ser:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El icono es 16x16 px, no le hago ningún cambio a sus proporciones ni nada del estilo.
Adjunto el código relacionado a la imagen por si es de utilidad.

```
    jLabel8.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\caiol\\Downloads\\cerrar.png")); // NOI18N
```

Agradezco las respuestas.

Comment: Lo primero que se me ocurre es que es un png alomejor al ampliarlo o al reducirlo pierde calidad, esto siempre pasa con imagenes. En cambio si usaras vectores no te pasaría nunca esto ya que un vector por mucho que lo hagas grande o pequeño siempre te mantiene la calidad.

Comment: Okey, pero, ¿qué tan aplicable son los vectores en Swing?

Comment: No hay soporte nativo para SVG en Java Swing. Trata de comenzar con un svg, edítalo en gimp o similar para exportarlo y tratar de conservar la calidad. Prueba con PNG y con JPG, a ver cómo te va

Comment: La segunda imagen no es 16x16.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontre la solucion al problema de la calidad de imagen, en el buscador del escritorio escribes "Configuración de Pantalla", lo mas probable es que en la escala lo tengas en 125%(Recomendado). Cambia esto al 100% y las imágenes en netbeans ya no serán borrosas[image: Configuración de pantalla]